# You can't use a list as a default argument, but can you use a tuple instead?

Tags: python, list, tuples, arguments, definition

Please let me know if there is a post already addressing it, I haven't been able to find a specific answer on this specific topic.

You shouldn't use a list as a default value for a function argument because it is mutable. Which of the following codes is the best practice in this case?

```
def my_func(arg1 = ("hello", "world")):
    pass
```

or

```
def my_func(arg1 = None):
    if arg1 is None:
        arg1 = ["hello", "world"]
```

I am talking about a situation in which a tuple and a list can be used the same way inside the function.

Thanks!

Comment: Well it depends if you wish it to be mutable or not..

Comment: They aren't equivalent, so it depends on what you *mean*

Answer (score 0):

Depends whether you want to alter it or not:

For tuple:

```
def my_func(arg1 = ("hello", "world")):
    arg1[0] = "other val"
```

You will get --> `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`

list is mutable as mentioned:

```
def my_func(arg1 = None):
    if arg1 is None:
        arg1 = ["hello", "world"]
    arg1[0] = "other val"
```

`arg1` is `['other val', 'world']`